# HTML5 & javascript - drawImage seems to trigger after animation completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, drawimage

I'm trying to create the following animation:
- when the page loads, I load the 2 components of my logo and draw them onto the canvas
- after clicking the animate button, both images should smoothly move up to the top of the page and shrink

However, it seems that the drawImage() only takes place somewhere after the entire animation has been completed even though I can see it being executed at the right time in the console. Commenting out the clearRect function also shows me that every frame is actually drawn onto the screen, but sadly they all appear together after the animation should be completed.

I'm pretty new to canvases and relevant tutorials on such animations are scarce and don't get me much further.

Here's the relevant script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var logoCanvas;
var logoContext;
var direction = 1;
var logoAnimationDuration = 2000; //millisec
var frameSpeed = 30/1000; //frames per second
var logoImageRatio = 0;
var logoTextRatio = 0;
var initialLogoImageHeight = 0;
var initialLogoTextHeight = 0;
var initialLogoImageTop = 0;
var initialLogoImageLeft = 0;
var initialLogoTextTop = 0;
var initialLogoTextLeft = 0;
var newLogoImageLeft = 0;
var logoImageWidth = 0;
var logoImageHeight = 0;
var logoTextWidth = 0;
var logoTextHeight = 0;
var logoImageTop = 0;
var logoImageLeft = 0;
var logoTextTop = 0;
var logoTextLeft = 0; 
var logoImageLoaded = false;
var logoTextLoaded = false;
var logoImage = new Image();
var logoText = new Image();
function AnimateFrontPageCanvas() {
    if(logoCanvas.height <= $('#Page_0').height()) {
        logoCanvas.height = $('#Page_0').height();
        return;
    }
    if(logoImageHeight <= $('#Page_0').height() - 4) {
        return; 
    }
    if(logoImageTop <= 2) {
        return; 
    }
    //logoCanvas.height = parseFloat(logoCanvas.height) - (parseFloat(window.innerHeight) - parseFloat($('#Page_0').height())) * 1/frameSpeed * 1/logoAnimationDuration;
    logoContext.clearRect(0, 0, logoCanvas.width, logoCanvas.height);
    AnimateLogo();

    setTimeout(AnimateFrontPageCanvas(), 1/frameSpeed);
}
function AnimateLogo() {
    AnimateLogoImage();
    AnimateLogoText();
}
function AnimateLogoImage() {
    logoImageHeight = logoImageHeight - (initialLogoImageHeight - $('#Page_0').height() + 4) * (1/frameSpeed) * (1/logoAnimationDuration);
    logoImageWidth = logoImageHeight*logoImageRatio;

    logoImageTop = logoImageTop - (initialLogoImageTop - 2)*(1/frameSpeed) * (1/logoAnimationDuration);
    logoImageLeft = logoImageLeft - (initialLogoImageLeft - newLogoImageLeft) * (1/frameSpeed) * (1/logoAnimationDuration); 

    logoContext.drawImage(logoImage, logoImageLeft, logoImageTop, logoImageWidth, logoImageHeight);
    var time = new Date();
    time = time.getTime();
    console.log('logoimage drawn: ' + time);
}
function AnimateLogoText() {
    logoTextHeight = logoTextHeight - (initialLogoTextHeight - $('#Page_0').height() + 4) * (1/frameSpeed) * (1/logoAnimationDuration);
    logoTextWidth = logoTextHeight*logoTextRatio;

    logoTextTop = logoTextTop - (initialLogoTextTop - 2) * (1/frameSpeed)*(1/logoAnimationDuration);
    logoTextLeft = logoTextLeft - (initialLogoTextLeft - newLogoTextLeft)*(1/frameSpeed)*(1/logoAnimationDuration); 

    logoContext.drawImage(logoText, logoTextLeft, logoTextTop, logoTextWidth, logoTextHeight);
    var time = new Date();
    time = time.getTime();
    console.log('logotext drawn: ' + time); 
}
function InitiateFrontPageCanvas() {    
    logoImage.onload = function() {
        logoImageLoaded = true;
        AfterImagesLoadedActions();
    }
    logoImage.src = '/site_mats/images/logo_image.png';
    logoText.onload = function() {
        logoTextLoaded = true;
        AfterImagesLoadedActions();
    }
    logoText.src = '/site_mats/images/logo_text.png';
}
function AfterImagesLoadedActions() {
    if(logoImageLoaded && logoTextLoaded) {
        logoImageRatio = logoImage.width/logoImage.height;
        logoTextRatio = logoText.width/logoText.height;

        if(logoImage.width > 0.8*logoCanvas.width) {
            logoImage.width = 0.8*logoCanvas.width;
            logoImage.height = logoImage.width/logoImageRatio;
        }

        if(logoText.width > 0.8*logoCanvas.width) {
            logoText.width = 0.8*logoCanvas.width;
            logoText.height = logoText.width/logoTextRatio;
        }

        if(parseFloat(logoImage.height) + parseFloat(logoText.height) > 0.66*logoCanvas.height) {
            var x = (0.66*logoCanvas.height)/(parseFloat(logoImage.height) + parseFloat(logoText.height));
            logoImage.height = x*logoImage.height;
            logoImage.width = logoImage.height*logoImageRatio;
            logoText.height = x*logoText.height;
            logoText.width = logoText.height*logoTextRatio;
        }

        initialLogoImageHeight = logoImage.height;
        initialLogoTextHeight = logoText.height;

        logoImageHeight = logoImage.height;
        logoImageWidth = logoImage.width;
        logoTextHeight = logoText.height;
        logoTextWidth = logoText.width;

        initialLogoImageTop = parseFloat((logoCanvas.height-(parseFloat(logoImageHeight)+parseFloat(logoTextHeight)))/2);
        initialLogoImageLeft = parseFloat((logoCanvas.width-logoImageWidth)/2);
        initialLogoTextTop = parseFloat(((logoCanvas.height-(parseFloat(logoImageHeight)+parseFloat(logoTextHeight)))/2)+parseFloat(logoImageHeight));
        initialLogoTextLeft = parseFloat((logoCanvas.width-logoImageWidth)/2);

        logoImageTop = initialLogoImageTop;
        logoImageLeft = initialLogoImageLeft;
        logoTextTop = initialLogoTextTop;
        logoTextLeft = initialLogoTextLeft;

        newLogoImageLeft = parseFloat(2);
        newLogoTextLeft = parseFloat((logoCanvas.width-$('#Page_0').height()*logoTextRatio)/2);;

        logoContext.drawImage(logoText, logoTextLeft, logoTextTop, logoTextWidth, logoTextHeight);
        logoContext.drawImage(logoImage, logoImageLeft, logoImageTop, logoImageWidth, logoImageHeight);

        //remove onload from image objects
        logoImage.onload = null;
        logoText.onload = null;
    }
}
function SetFrontPageCanvas() {     
    logoCanvas = document.getElementById('LogoCanvas');
    logoContext = logoCanvas.getContext('2d');
    logoCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    logoCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    logoContext.clearRect(0, 0, logoCanvas.width, logoCanvas.height);
    InitiateFrontPageCanvas();
}
window.onload = function() {
    SetFrontPageCanvas();
};
$(document).ready(function() {  
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    //alert($(window).width() + ' - ' + $(window).height());    
    logoImageLoaded = false;
    logoTextLoaded = false; 
    SetFrontPageCanvas();                 
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
});
</script>
```

And here's the relevant html:

```
<canvas id="LogoCanvas" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1;"></canvas>
<div id="Page_0" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:5;width:100%;height:90px;">
<div align="center" style="position:fixed;bottom:5px;z-index:100;width:100%;">
    <input type="button" onClick="AnimateFrontPageCanvas()" value="Animate">
</div>
```

If desired, the code can also be seen in action here: http://villa-gloria-katouna.com/site_mats/animation.php

Comment: not sure is this is the case, but your call to `setTimeout(AnimateFrontPageCanvas(), 1/frameSpeed);` has invalid syntax. it should be `setTimeout(AnimateFrontPageCanvas, 1/frameSpeed);` as you are calling the function at once instead of giving the function as a callback to `setTimeout`

Comment: IMHO relying on JS timers for animation is a bad idea. They tend to not work continuously when browser gets busy. I would think towards SVG animation

Comment: You are absolutely right and this solved my problem. I feel pretty dumb overlooking this silly error.
I will definitely have a look at SVG animation (as said, I'm pretty new to animations and such), do you have any articles/links you can recommend?

Comment: I would recommend testing your approach on several browsers and system load before making big decisions